# Invalid type (closure) for a variable that is not a function

Tags: r, loess

```
loess.smooth <- function(dat) {
  dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]

  ## response
  vars <- colnames(dat)
  ## covariate
  id <- 1:nrow(dat)
  ## define a loess filter function (fitting loess regression line)
  loess.filter <- function (x, span) loess(formula = paste(x, "id", sep = "~"),
                                           data = dat,
                                           degree = 1,
                                           span = span)$fitted 
  ## apply filter column-by-column
  new.dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(vars, loess.filter, span = 0.75),
                           col.names = colnames(dat))
}
```

When I try to apply `loess.smooth` to a dataframe, I get the error:

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = paste(x, "id", sep = "~"), data = dat) : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable 'id'
```

I don't understand why this is a problem since `id` is not a function, which is implied by the error. 
When I run through these lines of code outside of the function, it works perfectly fine and does exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a scoping issue involving passing a vector of strings to the `loess` function instead of passing a vector of formulas. The problem is that the environment returns `NULL` for the former, so `loess` doesn't know where to find it. If you wrap the formula in `as.formula` it works. This variable will be assigned the local environment inside the function call by default.

As to the cryptic error, it happens when you name a variable the same name of a given function from another package that is loaded, since if a function doesn't find a variable in the local environment, it will scope in the loaded packages for the function. In my case, the `id` function was loaded by the `dplyr` library.